# Performance of joining SCD Type 2 tables in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, scd

I have a 2 tables in Hive which are managed using SCD Type 2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row). Basically, each record has 2 columns valid_start_date and valid_end_date to specify the period during which it is valid.

The 2 tables:

**Employee** (Notice that employee_id 1 changed their address on 2010-10-20)

```
employee_id    employee_name    employee_address    valid_start_date    valid_end_date
1              Bob              123 XXX             2010-01-01          2010-10-20 
2              Alice            999 YYY             2010-01-01          9999-12-31
1              Bob              567 ZZZ             2010-10-20          9999-12-31
```

**Workplace** (Notice that employee_id 1 changed building on 2010-12-31)

```
employee_id    building_id    valid_start_date    valid_end_date
1              1              2010-01-01          2010-12-31
1              2              2010-12-31          9999-12-31
2              2              2010-01-01          9999-12-31
```

I want to join them and get this result

```
employee_id    employee_name    employee_address    building_id    valid_start_date    valid_end_date
1              Bob              123 XXX             1              2010-01-01          2010-10-20
1              Bob              567 ZZZ             1              2010-10-20          2010-12-31
1              Bob              567 ZZZ             2              2010-12-31          9999-12-31
2              Alice            999 YYY             1              2010-01-01          9999-12-31
```

This is the query that I came up with

```sql
WITH
  valid_dates AS (
    SELECT
        employee_id
      , valid_start_date    valid_date
    FROM
      employee
    UNION
    SELECT
        employee_id
      , valid_end_date      valid_date
    FROM
      employee
    UNION
    SELECT
        employee_id
      , valid_start_date    valid_date
    FROM
      workplace
    UNION
    SELECT
        employee_id
      , valid_end_date      valid_date
    FROM
      workplace
  ),
  valid_date_ranges AS (
    SELECT
        employee_id
      , valid_start_date
      , valid_end_date
    FROM (
      SELECT
          employee_id
        , valid_date                     valid_start_date
        , LEAD(valid_date, 1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY employee_id
            ORDER BY valid_date)         valid_end_date
      FROM
        valid_dates
    ) valid_date_ranges_with_null
    WHERE
      valid_end_date IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT
    vdr.employee_id
  , e.employee_name
  , e.employee_address
  , wp.building_id
  , vdr.valid_start_date
  , vdr.valid_end_date
FROM
  employee e
INNER JOIN
  valid_date_ranges vdr
ON
  e.employee_id = vdr.employee_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN -- there may be employees without workplace
  workplace wp
ON
  wp.employee_id = vdr.employee_id
WHERE
      e.valid_start_date < vdr.valid_end_date
  AND e.valid_end_date > vdr.valid_start_date
  AND wp.valid_start_date < vdr.valid_end_date
  AND wp.valid_end_date > vdr.valid_start_date
;
```

I seems to produce the correct result but I want my query to run faster (this is currently the bottle neck of my pipeline). Also, I have to do the same thing with up to 5 tables joining together and up to 3 billion rows each so I really hope there is a way to optimize this query. Can you help me please? Thank you!

I'm on Hive 2.1.0 and there is no non-equi join yet by the way.